# How to call a jQuery function with a dropdown so that the dropdown's onChange will refresh the div, not just add the function result to it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

#### Background

I give this background in case I am thinking about things the wrong way, which it seems likely I am. I am trying to implement a timezone dropdown that then runs this jQuery code (
https://github.com/shonihei/weekly-scheduler-component ) on a target div. All of the code is in the HTML file. It's a fairly long function that creates a grid of divs with column headers as days of the week and row headers as 1-hour-block start times, and enables the user to select the divs. I didn't want to paste all the code into here, so assume it's within my `<script>` tags. The use scenario behind my integration is:

1. I have certain times available. E.g. 1PM to 5PM MST. I only show blocks for those times.
2. The user selects their timezone from the dropdown. E.g. PST.
3. Based on their dropdown selection, my times are converted to their timezone in the scheduler, and the display is updated so that my times show in their times. E.g. They see 12PM to 4PM blocks.
4. They can select a different timezone in the dropdown and get an updated schedule table for that timezone.

I have had a number of issues in my attempts. One is that I have a new table displayed on every dropdown change, resulting in the page showing table after table. Another is that I really don't understand how the dropdown SHOULD call jQuery to refresh the target div with a new calendar. This question is to understand how I should think about this dropdown using the jQuery function that creates this scheduler, and see how it's properly done. I searched for how to reset or empty the div, but I'm not sure that's actually what I need. I am a jQuery newbie.

#### Code

Here is the HTML, with jQuery that doesn't work.

```
<label for="timezone_selector">Please select a time zone:</label>
<select id="timezone_selector"
            required="required"
            onChange="$('#target').weekly_schedule()"> 
    
   <option value="" selected="selected" hidden="hidden">Click here</option>      
   <option value="gmt-7">Pacific, PDT (Daylight Savings) GMT-7</option>
   <option value="gmt-8">Pacific, PST (Standard) GMT-8</option>
   <option value="gmt-6">Mountain, MDT (Daylight Savings) GMT-6</option>
   <option value="gmt-7">Mountain, MST (Standard) GMT-7</option>
   <option value="gmt-5">Central, CDT (Daylight Savings) GMT-5</option>
   <option value="gmt-6">Central, CST (Standard) GMT-6</option>
   <option value="gmt-4">Eastern, EDT (Daylight Savings) GMT-4</option>
   <option value="gmt-5">Eastern, EST (Standard) GMT-5</option>
</select>

<div class="container" style="margin: auto; width: 50%; height: 75%; 
                              display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center;">
   <div id="target">
   </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried

```
    <script>
        $("#timezone_selector").change(function() {
            $('#target').weekly_schedule();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: "One is that I have a new table displayed on every dropdown change, resulting in the page showing table after table" maybe you should delete the last table every dropdown change?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. ```$('#target').empty(); $('#target').weekly_schedule();``` works. Is this sensible, or should I be using something else?

Comment: If API that you are using doesn't suggest anything to that, then I think it is sensible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As conceptually suggested by @MichaelChon, I've tried deleting the table first thing when the dropdown changes , which I found I could do with `.empty()`

```
<script>
   $("#timezone_selector").change(function() {
      $('#target').empty();
      $('#target').weekly_schedule();
   });
</script>
```

Seems to work well.